# Test that All Routes are Configred Secure

Tags: php, laravel, https

Is there anyway to **force** Laravel to treat all your routes as HTTPs irrespective of what you've configuration in routes.php?

That is, I know I can configure a route securely withsomething like this

```
Route::get('/logout', array('https', 'as'=>'logout'
```

What I'd like is for the `https` to be added to all routes automatically, even if a developer does this

```
Route::get('/logout', array('https', 'as'=>'logout'
```

ensuring a secure route if a developer fails to specify a route as secure.

Failing that, (before I dig into it myself) is there a known programmatic way to get a list of all routes and check if they're secure or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can force them by creating a before filter to check if the current request is secure or not:

```
App::before(function($request)
{
    if( ! Request::secure())
    {
        return Redirect::secure(Request::fullUrl());
    }
});
```

You also can create a filter:

```
Route::filter('force.ssl', function()
{
    if( ! Request::secure())
    {
        return Redirect::secure(Request::fullUrl());
    }
});
```

And apply to a group of routes:

```
Route::group(['before' => 'force.ssl', function() {

    Route::get('test', 'Controller@action');

});
```

You can still check them all one by one this way:

```
$router = App::make('router');

foreach($router->getRoutes() as $route)
{
    var_dump($route->secure());
}
```

Comment: +1 for useful information, but what happens when the request has additional query string parameters?  Or is a post?

Comment: Not sure if Laravel would ever loose your query data, but... Edited to provide a way to check them all.

Comment: Thanks for the getRoutes method, just what I was looking for.  Re: not losing data -- the code you have above `return Redirect::secure(Request::path());` wouldn't include any query string parameters, and we're running into a similar problem with something in one of the laravel redirect methods we're using.  We're unsure what it is, but forcing URLs to be secure fixes the problem for now while we slot a longer term investigation for a maintenance release.

Comment: Oh! Sorry, just updated to fullUrl(), which includes the query too.

Comment: Awesome, I didn't know about that method!

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to make all routes secure, why not just add a permanent redirect in Apache or Nginx from HTTP to HTTPS?

Then you bypass having to deal with specifying all of that in your routes?

Otherwise if you are dead set on doing it like you are now, I believe you can do a Route::when() to check if it is secure or not.

```
Route::when('*', function($route, $request)
{
    if( ! $request->secure())
    {
        return Redirect::secure($request->path());
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 for useful information, but there's times/methods when Laravel will generate an insecure URL, even if you're browsing from a secure context, and a webserver redirect won't always pass along all the parameters, cookies, etc.  We've worked around these problems by forcing an HTTPS in the routing.

Comment: Do you have any examples of Laravel not generating a secure URL? Laravel uses whatever is in the HOST header. I can't think of any time it would do something otherwise.